# React Navigation - Como esconder uma tela do menu que está dentro de Bottom Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Criei uma rota em meu aplicativo usando o Tab.Navigator, e todas as telas que coloco dentro da rota ele gera um ícone no menu do aplicativo, porém gostaria de criar uma tela de 'detalhes' e não quero que seja gerado um ícone no menu para essa tela em especifico.

```
function AppTab() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
                let iconName;

                switch (route.name) {
                    case 'List':
                        iconName = 'list';
                        break;
                    case 'Map':
                        iconName = 'map';
                        break;
                    case 'Post':
                        iconName = 'plus-circle';
                        break;
                    case 'Gallery':
                        iconName = 'check-square';
                        break;
                    case 'User':
                        iconName = 'user';
                        break;
                }

                return <Icon name={iconName} size={31} color={color} />;
            },
        })}

            initialRouteName="Map"
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="List" component={ListPage} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Map" component={Map} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Post" component={CreateProblem} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Gallery" component={GalleryPage} />
            <Tab.Screen name="User" component={UserPage} />
            
            <Tab.Screen name="Detail" component={DatailPage} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Mesmo que dentro do meu switch case eu remova o ícone para essa tela, um espaço vazio sera gerado e ainda assim sera possível navegar para ela pelo menu inferior.

Não sei se cometi um erro conceitual e isso não é possível dentro desta biblioteca, e neste caso tereia que substituir tudo por uma Stack Navigator e criar eu mesmo o menu inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, sou iniciante em React Native e tbm estava com essa duvida, tenho um projeto que possui varias telas que não tem a tab bar. A solução que achei seria ter dois tipos de navegações, um tab bar e o outro stack.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: 80,
          paddingHorizontal: 35,
          paddingBottom: 20,
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#D35400",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Inicio"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="store" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Pedido"
        component={Order}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="clipboard-list"
              size={size}
              color={color}
            />
          ),
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MyList"
        component={MyList}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
            <Ionicons name="ios-bookmark" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="user" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function Routes() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="DeliciousFood"
        component={DeliciousFood}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn_Up"
        component={SignIn_Up}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignIn}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignUp"
        component={SignUp}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Tabs}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

No meu caso na tela "home" no component chamei a função "tabs", sendo assim a partir dessa tela é que vai aparecer a tab bar.

Sei que no seu caso é o contrario, acho que é só adaptar esse meu exemplo. Espero ter ajudado.